# How to display the results from a separate PHP file in an HTML page?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to display the sum in the HTML form page itself. A part of the code is given below in my PHP file:

```
<?php 
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>
    <?php
      $sum=$sum+$row['value']; 
    ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $row['id'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['time'];?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['value'];?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

In my HTML form I have a `total` button. When I click that, I need to display the sum value. How can I do that?

```
<form action="php_html_table_data_filter3.php" method="post">
  From:<input type="text" name="valueToSearch1"><br><br>
  To:<input type="text" name="valueToSearch2"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
  <button type="button">Total</button><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: the .html & .php files are separate?

Comment: @pAsh the files are separate

Comment: Assign value to hidden field. Once click on "Total" Button, get value from hidden field and show wherever you want.

Comment: Another more secure way is to use AJAX. Store sum on server side. Once click on "Total" button make ajax call and show ajax response as a sum.

Comment: What about the table rows `<tr>`? How are you using those? Do they need to be in the result as well?

Answer (score 0):

As I assume that you want to show total, if it is correct then follow below method

```
 $sum = 0;

     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)):?>

       $sum+= $row['value'];

    <?php endwhile;?>

    echo $sum;
```

or

if you want to show result without reloading the page. you have to code in ajax request.

Comment: but i want to display it on the same form page itself

Comment: then you have to code onclick ajax request using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

We use ajax in html page to access the content from the php page :

```
HTML:
<html>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> // script download
<form action="php_html_table_data_filter3.php" method="post">
  From:<input type="text" name="valueToSearch1"><br><br>
  To:<input type="text" name="valueToSearch2"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
  <button type="button" id="total">Total</button><br><br>
  Your sum:<span id="sum"></span>
</form>
</html>
<script>
$( "#total" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "phptest.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data)
        {
           $('#sum').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>

PHP: here your php code
<?php 
echo "10";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [**PHP SESSIONs**](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp), and play with the information you're sending in the POST request. Basically, both buttons will need to be of type submit so that they both send the request to the process (process.php). Then you can use sessions to set your results.

Do it in this manner:

**index.php**

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<form action="process.php" method="post">
    From:<input type="text" name="valueToSearch1"><br><br>
    To:<input type="text" name="valueToSearch2"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
    <button name="total_btn" type="submit">Total</button>
</form>

<div id="results">
    <?= (!empty($_SESSION["table"])) ? $_SESSION["table"] : "" ?>
    <br>
    <?= (!empty($_SESSION["sum"])) ? "Sum: " . $_SESSION["sum"] : "" ?>
</div>
<?php
session_destroy();
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

$sum = 0;
$table = "<table>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result)) {
    $sum += $row['value'];
    $table .= "<tr>
                  <td>{$row['id']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['time']}</td>
                  <td>{$row['value']}</td>
               </tr>";
}
$table .= "</table>";

if (isset($_POST['total_btn'])) {
    $_SESSION["sum"] = $sum;
}
$_SESSION["table"] = $table;
header('Location: index.php');
```

Answer (score -1):

if i understood your problem correctly, then u need Ajax call. GET or POST based on your preferences.on that your HTML code will be separate from php code basically php code will respond to Ajax call and give you out put.

Modified code- **Test.html**

```
<form action="php_html_table_data_filter3.php" method="post">
        From:<input type="text" name="valueToSearch1"><br><br>
        To:<input type="text" name="valueToSearch2"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="search" value="Filter"><br><br>
        <button type="button" id="gettotal">Total</button><br><br>

    </form>

<script>

$("#gettotal").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',//based on your choice or requirement
    url: 'calculate.php',
    success: function(response) {
       //here u decide where to show output value

         alert(response);

    },
    error: function(result) {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

**calculate.php**

```
<?php 
$sum = 0;
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($search_result))
  {
   //calculate your total and send back as JSON obj.
      $sum=$sum+$row['value']; 
  }
 echo json_encode($sum);
?>
```

Comment: sum is displayed in the next page